# return в function

Tags: php, функции

При написание кода столкнутся с такой проблемой.

использую `class`.
но нужно чтобы в случае если из function возвратит false, то выходить из class ( поможет return ).

но есть проблема, писать я if() для каждой функции отдельно не хочу, а использование ?? или ?, в них нельзя использовать return

Comment: https://bash.im/quote/393460

Comment: Напишите один раз какой-либо хэлпер для вашей ситуэйшен, `$helper->checkFunc($this->yourFunc());` , `checkFunc()` - будет соержать именно тот `if`, который вы не хотите писать, если уж вам так конструкция `if..else` нравится.